# How can I get access to HttpInterceptor from normal service?

Tags: angular, httpclient, angular-http-interceptors

Currently I need to create two instances of the same class to access some variables inside the `HttpInterceptor`. Is there a way to resolve the provider with just one instance and allows me to use the same interceptor class in normal service and as interceptor?

***.module.ts**

```
.
.
Providers:[
 CustomInterceptor, // first class instance
 {
  Provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
  UseClass: CustomInterceptor, // second class instance
  multi: true,
 }
],
.
.
```

**http.service.ts**

```
constructor(
 interceptor: CustomInterceptor,
){}

interceptor.hasNext$.next(true);
```

**CustomInterceptor.ts**

```
hasNext$ = new BehaviourSubject(false);
```

When I call the interceptor in the `http.service.ts`, I access the first `CustomInterceptor` while the request I make to the httpClient is the second instance of `CustomInterceptor`. Therefore my `hasNext$.next(true)` in the `http.service.ts` will never change in the second one.

Someone suggested that I should use,

```
Providers: [
 CustomInterceptor,
 {
  provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
  useValue: CustomInterceptor,
  multi: true,
 },
]
```

but the above code will throw an error, because HTTP_INTERCEPTORS token requeires useClass and base on my understanding that will class an instance of the same class.

**UPDATE**

Just found a way to write to work around this.

**http.service.ts**

```
constructor(
 @Inject(HTTP_INTERCEPTOS) protected interceptor: CustomInterceptor,
){}

interceptor.hasNext$.next(true);
```

Comment: Add source code examples of what you've tried.

Comment: Please add some codes, or even better if you provide a stackblitz.com link to your issue

Comment: Updated my comments and my code are too coupled that i cannot code write in stackblitz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other way to get this to work without having to instantiate other token in the provider is manually inject the HTTP_INTERCEPTORS in the normal service.

**app.moudule.ts**

```
providers: [
 {
   provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
   useClass: CustomInterceptor,
   multi: true,
 }
],
```

**http.service.ts**

```
constructor (
 @Inject(HTTP_INTERCEPTORS) private interceptors: HttpInterceptors,
) {
 let interceptor = interceptors.find(x => x instanceOf CustomInterceptor);
 interceptor.hasNext$.next(true); // this way we have access to the same interceptor
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do the exact opposite of what you are trying to do.

Create a service (or use the current http service) that would hold the "shared" part (`hasNext$ = new BehaviourSubject(false);`) and then inject it into the `CustomInterceptor`.

Comment: thanks for answering my question, yes that thought came across my mind a few times, now that you are saying it makes me lend more toward that way.